# Python how to get multibyte variable size in 8-bit?

Tags: php, python, filesize, multibyte

I am fetching some remote binary file and saving it in the python variable.
How can i get its size .i.e size after the file storing on disk ? without actually storing on disk.

In php i am using it like this

```
<?php
$file_content contains remote downloaded binary file data.
echo mb_strlen($file_content, '8bit');
```

above code gives file size i.e. file data size stored in variable.

whats the equivalent of it in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the content of a `bytes` or bytestring is its length.

```
>>> len(b'12345')
5
```

Comment: so it means i need to use use len(file_content) ?

Comment: If `file_content` is the `bytes` or bytestring that contains the contents you have downloaded, yes.

Comment: Thanks , just tested and it does show exact bytes size.